# Get first value of InfoPath dropdown, not the ID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, dropdown, office, xpath

I'm trying to get first value of InfoPath dropdown. Dropdown is bound to a SharePoint lookup column. This is the XPath to get first value of InfoPath dropdown.

```
xdXDocument:GetDOM("OfficeApplications")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW[1]/d:Title
```

But this returns the lookup ID, not the value. How to get the lookup value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the default value of the lookup is ID.

**Your scenarios:**

List B has a lookup column (named “listA”) to List A’s “Title” column, List C has a lookup column (named “listB”) to List B’s “listA” lookup column.

You want to get the “listA” lookup column value from first item of List B.

**Solution:**

Need to filter the list A items based on the lookup ID from the lookup column (“listA”) of the first item in List B first item, then you can get the Title value instead of ID.

In this form, has two secondary data sources:

- listA --> the data source of List A
- listb --> the data source of List B

[image]